# Which cast is fastest?

Tags: c#, casting, types

Which cast is fastest in C#? Assume that I have a 64 bit floating point. Would it be faster to convert it to a 32 bit integer, or a 64 bit integer (assuming that data loss is not relevant to me)?

Comment: Is the speed of conversion (ever) really the limiting factor here?  You can try using System.Diagnostics and Stopwatch to time doing this a number of times.  Also, are you rounding?  Truncating?  Is the processor 64-bit?  Is the OS 64-bit?

Comment: I don't know, measure it.  Though it might depend on whether the current configuration supports native 64-bit types or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to find this out, each with their own advantages.

- experimental evidence: do a large number of each cast in a massive loop and time them, trying to keep all other possible factors consistent.
- look at the machine code for the two casts and do an proper analysis on which is faster.
- ask the developers.

Me, I would opt for the first choice as a first run since it's the easiest to do and doesn't involve any third parties. Only if it were unclear would I move to the second method.

And I wouldn't trust a third-party anyway unless they showed some evidence, and they might not get back to you before your homework deadline.